# Hybrid native looking components for Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have just began to learn MeteorJS and I am really impressed of its concepts, like database client-server sync, and of its easiness of use.

However, the tutorials which I have seen so far, do not speak about the GUI for Meteor-based hybrid apps. I mean visual components / widgets libraries.

I know that there is some integration with Ionic, but it looks too much overhead to include Ionic/Angular MVC framework and the Meteor Node.js in the single app.

May you suggest any lightweight GUI library with native look-n-feel?

Thank you very much in advance,
Ephraim

Comment: meteoric is without angular. check out ratchet as well

Answer (score 1):

If you want something **superfast** in regards to Web UI development **[Webix is really impressive](http://webix.com/)**. Here an integration example: [Webix integration with Meteor](https://github.com/webix-hub/webix-meteor-example)